# Django generic FormView not showing when included in other template

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-generic-views

First, what is currently working:

I have a form defined in `forms.py`:

```
class EnrollForm(forms.Form):
    course_id = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    def enroll(self):
        print(self.cleaned_data)
```

I build said form in a view in `views.py`:

```
class EnrollView(FormView):
    template_name = 'core/enroll.html'
    form_class = EnrollForm
    success_url=''

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.enroll()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I display it in `enroll.html`:

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Enroll" />
</form>
```

So, when I visit `localhost:8000/core/enroll/`, I see the form in all its might:
[image: working form]

However, when I attempt to include this file in another file using

```
{% include "core/enroll.html" %}
```

in another html file, that only displays the button while the `{{ form }}` tag in `enroll.html`doesn't resolve to anything and just silently fails, showing:

[image: dysfunctional form]

EDIT1: This is the file from which I am attempting to include the form:

```
<h1>{{ course.title }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<ul>
{# reverse lookup on codes with course foreignkey relationship #}
{% for code in course.code_set.all %}
  <li>{{ code.code }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% include "core/enroll.html" %}
```

Comment: Does the CCS for the template support the nested template? On your page try inspect element to view which HTML objects exist. It is possible the objects exist outside of the page's scope (container) and therefore, are not visible.

Comment: @t0bi I already checked this but forgot to add it to the post. There is no code on the page between the token and the submit button.

Comment: Strange. It might be helpful if you post more of the other template you are working with.

Comment: edited with code @t0bi

Answer (score 2):

So here is the thing. When you visit **localhost:8000/core/enroll/** django calls the view **EnrollView** where you define what the form is and pass it to context.

once in context, its html page, **enroll.html**, in this case knows what form variable is.

on the other hand when you visit another page, **EnrollView** is never gets called. the included partial **{% include "core/enroll.html" %}**, tries to render the form but does not know what form variable is.

## solution:

The view which is rendering the html page in question (where you want to see the form, but can not) should add **EnrollForm** in the context.

```
context['form'] = EnrollForm()
```

something like above line. Then you should be able to see form.

Comment: This seems sound but unfortunately the error persists when I create context and add the 'form' entry. Any ideas?

Comment: are there multiple forms on the new page ?

Comment: No, just the one